# sqlite3 foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite, composite-primary-key

I have a database made in sqlite3 and have set foreign keys on the loan table to the student table and book table to stop duplicate loans:

using **create table**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE loan(
  SudentID INTEGER,
  ISBN INTEGER,
  out INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(SudentID)
      REFERENCES student(SudentID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  FOREIGN KEY(ISBN)
      REFERENCES book(ISBN)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE student(
  SudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  First TEXT,
  Last,
  Contact Text,
  Year INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE book(
  ISBN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Title TEXT,
  Price INTEGER,
  Qty INTEGER,
  Subject TEXT)
```

If i try to insert a duplicate records into the **loan table** the foreign key **does not** prevent it.

**Pragma** is switched on both in the code and in Firefox database settings.

The version is 2.6.0

My work around is to use Distinct to filter out duplicates but is there any way I can activate them as I use this database as a teaching tool. However the `cascade delete` does not work! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a composite primary key on the loan table.

```
CREATE TABLE loan(
  StudentID INTEGER,
  ISBN INTEGER,
  out INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(SudentID)
      REFERENCES student(SudentID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  FOREIGN KEY(ISBN)
      REFERENCES book(ISBN)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  PRIMARY KEY(StudentID, ISBN)
)
```

Comment: This is what I would do normally but could not find the sql command in any of the books!

Comment: I can verify this works perfectly in version 2.6.0 of Sqlite3 as it has been tested practically.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key support is only available in Sqlite version 3.6.19 and upwards. So the problem may be one of the following:

1. Sqlite version < 3.6.19. To whether your version supports foreign key or not try the following:

> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;

If no data is return as opposed to *0* or *1*, then your version does not support foreign keys.

2. Your version of sqlite3 was compiled with either of these defined

> SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY
>
> SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER

One thing though, foreign keys are not enforced in sqlite3. Find all this information [from here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)